# ZSH Permission Denied When Executing Sublime Text

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

My user should have ownership to Sublime.

```
myusername@Andreass-Mini ~ % ls -l /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app
total 0
drwx------  8 myusername  admin  256 Jun 26  2021 Contents
myusername@Andreass-Mini ~ %
```

But I cannot execute it:

```
myusername@Andreass-Mini ~ % /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app 
zsh: permission denied: /Applications/Sublime Text.app
```

But I can open it:

```
myusername@Andreass-Mini ~ % open /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app
```

I used 755 and even 777

```
sudo chmod 755 /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app
```

And made sure that it's owned by the current user

```
myusername@Andreass-Mini ~ % sudo chown -R $(whoami) /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app
```

The Terminal has full disk access. The file is not locked. But I cannot execute it.

I have several scripts where I need to be able to execute it and open files with it. Can you point me what I missed in order to have the permission to execute it.

Comment: The lower case `d` in the output of `ls -l` means _directory_, which explains the error message you got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app` is the name of a folder, not an executable file. To run the program from the command line, you need to launch the executable, like this:

`/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/MacOS/sublime_text`